# Scroll to first error in jQuery without a warning in JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I would like to scroll to the first error in my Bootstrap form using jQuery.

I used:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($('.has-error').first().offset().top)
},500);
```

and it's working fine but there is one small issue. In JavaScript console I get:

> TypeError: $(...).first(...).offset(...) is undefined

if no elements with class `has-error` has been found (there are no errors). Of course if there is at least one element with this class, I get no warning.

I would like to remove this warning adding extra condition to check if `first()` returns object (it seems it always does but I would expect it to be empty if no element is found).

I tried to do the following:

```
var el = $('.has-error').first();
if (! $.isEmptyObject(el)) {
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (el.offset().top)
    },500);
}
```

but it doesn't change anything. In JavaScript console there is still warning.

Is there any way to remove this warning? Or maybe using `first()` method cause that it's not possible to catch when no element with this class exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the elements to check if there are any errors.

```
if ($(".has-error").length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($(".has-error").first().offset().top)
    },500);
}
```

The `length` function will return the number of elements found. In javascript, every number above 0 will be seen as `true`.

Comment: But this has side effect: first it goes to that element and then after 500ms scrolls back down

Answer (score 3):

If there are no errors, you should check whether .has-error exists, not only the first.

```
var el = $('.has-error');
if (el.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (el.first().offset().top)
    },500);
}
```